# Html form not being processed from PHP

Tags: php, html

I have this html form

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post">

    <div class="col-md-9">

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="name" placeholder="Your Name">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="email" placeholder="Your Email">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="subject" placeholder="Subject">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12">
        <textarea name="message" cols="1" rows="1" class="message" placeholder="Your message... " id="message"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send Message" id="submit" class="button templatemo_sendbtn">
      </div>

    </div>

  </form>
```

and this is my php that I found off the internet but I cannot make it work. Please help me. I am trying to add the php attached to the file but this editor wont allow me to. What seems to be happening is that once the form is filled out on the webpage, I am getting an error to go back and fix the code but I do not understand what the fault is as I have no knowledge of PHP.

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
     
    // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
    $email_to = "name@domain.com";
     
    $email_subject = "website html form submissions";
     
     
    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }
     
    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }
     
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required
     
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
     
    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }
     
    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
     
     
// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
 
<!-- place your own success html below -->
 
Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
 
<?php
}
die();
?>
```

After clicking submit/send the error message i am getting is:
We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. These errors appear below.

> We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.
>
> Please go back and fix these errors.

Comment: A. I don't see any PHP, and B. You need to be more specific with what problem(s) you're having. Stating: "*I cannot make it work*" is not offering up enough information. What is not working? What, if any, errors are you receiving? Etc.

Comment: sorry i have fixed my question

Comment: "*I am getting an error to go back and fix the code*" You'll need to post the error for starters. Please forfeit any/all relevant information to your issue. Otherwise, we're going to be going back-and-forth for an hour with people having to ask you for more information. Please post any/all errors you're seeing. E.g. Is the screen going *blank white*? Are you seeing something like "Notice: ... "?

Comment: I have added the error

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP code you're reaching the block, which is calling the `died()` function, which is haulting the script and producing that error message:

```
// validation expected data exists
if (!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}
```

The reason for this is because the script above is looking to see if several of the form fields have been sent/posted, to which they have not. You do not have a form `input` with `name="first_name"`, `name="last_name"`, `name="telephone"`, or `name="comments"`. So since this condition wasn't satisfying, it was throwing the `died()` function.

You can fix this by changing your HTML form, removing `name="name"`, and adding an `input` for *first_name`and`last_name`, changing`name="message"`to`name="comments"`, and adding an input for *telephone* :

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post">

    <div class="col-md-9">

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="name" placeholder="Your First Name">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="name" placeholder="Your Last Name">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" class="email" placeholder="Your Telephone">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="email" placeholder="Your Email">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="subject" placeholder="Subject">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12">
        <textarea name="comments" cols="1" rows="1" class="message" placeholder="Your message... " id="comments"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send Message" id="submit" class="button templatemo_sendbtn">
      </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

**EDIT**

The following conditions must also be met:

```
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
}
```

Meaning you must enter a valid email address (Eg. example@example.com), a first name (E.g. John), a last name (E.g. Doe), and 2 or more characters into the `comments` textarea box in the form.

Comment: Thank you Marcus. This has not resolved the error and returns the same. Would it work if the died function is removed?

Comment: Are you actually *filling out* the form by entering a valid email address, a first/last name, and some comments?

Comment: I have removed the validation but now the telephone number and first name is not coming up in the form once it is submitted